# Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule) in angular 4 or angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-promise

this is my `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { NgFlashMessagesModule } from 'ng-flash-messages';
import { NgxfUploaderModule } from 'ngxf-uploader';
import { NgxUploaderModule } from 'ngx-uploader';
import { NumberDirective } from './number.directive';
import { FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FirstPageComponent,
    SavePasswordComponent,
    LoginPageComponent,
    VerifyDetailsComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    ViewOfferLetterComponent,
    ContactOptionComponent,
    SocialLinksComponent,
    ContactUsComponent,
    CompanyDetailsComponent,
    CompanyVisionComponent,
    SaveInformationComponent,
    AboutUsComponent,
    ComponyHistoryComponent,
    TestimonialComponent,
    AllocateOfficeComponent,
    NumberDirective,
    FacilitiesComponent,
    FirstDayRuleComponent,
    CompanyMediaComponent,
    HeaderPagesComponent,
    TestImageGallaryComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    NgxfUploaderModule,
    NgxUploaderModule,
    NgFlashMessagesModule.forRoot(),
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(
    appRoutes,  // { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    ),
    ModalGalleryModule.forRoot() // <----------------- angular-modal-gallery module import
  ],
  providers: [
    GlobalService,
    AuthguardGuard,
    SuperAdmiApiService,
    EmployeeApiService,
    CookieService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

this is my component in which error can generated

```
       import { Component, OnInit, VERSION, NgModule, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// import {EventModel} from '../../models/EventModel';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { EmployeeApiService } from '../../../config-pages/employee-api.service';
import { GlobalService } from '../../../config-pages/global.service';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { GridLayout, Image, PlainGalleryConfig, PlainGalleryStrategy } from 'angular-modal-gallery';
export interface Image {
  id: number;
  text: string;
}
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { async } from '../../../../../node_modules/rxjs/internal/scheduler/async';
interface JQuery {
  center(): JQuery;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-image-gallary',
  templateUrl: './test-image-gallary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-image-gallary.component.css']
})
@Injectable()
export class TestImageGallaryComponent implements OnInit, Resolve<any> {

  name: string;
  compid: any;
  candidateid: any;
  Response: any;
  gallaryData: any;
  responseMessage: any;
  imageUrl: any;
  Image = [];
  isDataAvailable: any;
  data: any;
  i: any;
  asyncResult: any;
  htmlToAdd: any;
  plainGalleryGrid: PlainGalleryConfig = {
    strategy: PlainGalleryStrategy.GRID,
    layout: new GridLayout({ width: '86px', height: '86px' }, { length: 3, wrap: true })
  };
  constructor(private EmployeeApi: EmployeeApiService, private _global: GlobalService, private cookieService: CookieService) {
    this.candidateid = this.cookieService.get('candidateid');
    this.compid = this.cookieService.get('companyid');
    this.imageUrl = this._global.CompanyImagePath;
}
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
   ): Observable<any[]> {
   this.data = this.EmployeeApi.getimagegallarydata(this.compid, this.candidateid ).pipe(map(
      resultArray => {
    this.Response = resultArray;
    if (this.Response.status === 200) {
        this.gallaryData = this.Response.gallarydata;
        for ( this.i = 0; this.i < this.gallaryData.length; this.i++) {
          // alert(this.i);
          this.Image[this.i] =
            new Image(
              this.i,
              { // modal
                img: this.imageUrl + this.gallaryData[this.i].filename,
                extUrl: 'http://www.google.com'
              }
            );
        }
        console.log(this.Image);
      } else {
      this.responseMessage = 'Gallary not available';
      alert(this.responseMessage);
    }
    }
    )
  );
  return void(0);
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.pageload();
}
 // set page ui according to screen size
 pageload() {
  $.fn.center = function () {
    this.css('position', 'absolute');
    this.css('top', Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) +
     $(window).scrollTop()) + 'px');
     this.css('left', Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px');
       return this;
   };
   $('#abc0').center();
}
}
```

[image: staric injectore error in angular 4]
I have an problem of static injectore problem in angular 6, actually i import 
httpclientmodule in app.module.ts and ad is in import array

Comment: can you share your code? your component, and app.module.ts

Comment: Can you also copy the whole error here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use your component as a resolver.

Resolvers are intended to be service-like in that they should be registered in your module's `providers` array - I suspect this is why you receive the injector error.

Ideally you should split your `resolve` to a separate class, decorate it with `@Injectable`, and reference it in your module's `providers` array.

Your resolver would look something like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class TestImageGallaryComponentResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    // Get your data here and return it. This class can receive dependencies in the constructor.
  }
}
```

Your router config would look something like this:

```js
{
  path: 'gallery'
  component: TestImageGallaryComponent,
  resolve: {
    data: TestImageGallaryComponentResolver
  }
}
```

And your component can access the data as follows:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-image-gallary',
  templateUrl: './test-image-gallary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-image-gallary.component.css']
})
export class TestImageGallaryComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    activatedRoute.data.subscribe(resolvedData => {
      // Do stuff with resolvedData.data
    });
  }
}
```

Using a component as its own resolver is not a thing that has ever occurred to me, but I'm fairly sure it won't work. If you add the component to the `providers` array it may well run, but the data won't end up where you expect it to.

The injector will provide the "component" used for resolving as a singleton, and will provide an entirely different instance of the component when it is requested by the view. Components are freshly instantiated when requested, whereas everything in the `providers` array is a singleton.

The [angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) features a reasonably in depth example of how to use resolvers.

Answer (score 0):

You Just Declared **TestImageGallaryComponent** But not imported in `app.module.ts`

Like:

```
import { TestImageGallaryComponent } from 'Some-path';
```